# Interpolation curve with opengl using evaluators

Tags: c, opengl, interpolation, bezier, opengl-compat

This code almost works, but the problem is that it leaves behind the last control point like if it doesn't exist. I cannot find the error and I don't know why, I checked the transformation matrix and the converted control point many times but nothing

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Begin globals.
static int numVal = 0;

// Final control points.
static float controlPoints[4][3] =
{
    {-30.0, 0.0, 0.0}, { -10.0, 20.0, 0.0},
    {10.0, -20.0, 0.0}, {30.0, 0.0, 0.0}
};



//Matrix multiplication Mb^-1 * Mi
static float conversion[4][4] =
{
    {1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},{-0.8333,3.0,-1.5,0.3333},{0.3333,-1.5,3.0,-0.8333},{0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0}
};


//End globals

//Control point conversion for evaluator
void convertcp(float ctrlpoints[4][3]){
    int i,j,k;
    float tot = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < 4;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < 4;j++){
            ctrlpoints[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < 3;k++){
                ctrlpoints[i][j] += conversion[i][k] * controlPoints[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

// End globals.

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void){glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);}


// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    int indx;
    float ctrlpoints[4][3];
    convertcp(ctrlpoints);


    // Draw the control polygon in light gray.
    glColor3f(0.7,0.7, 0.7);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (indx = 0; indx < 4; indx++)
        glVertex3fv(controlPoints[indx]);
    glEnd();

    // Specify and enable the Bezier curve.
    glMap1f(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0.0, 1.0, 3, 4, &ctrlpoints[0][0]);
    glEnable(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3);

    // Draw the Bezier curve by defining a sample grid and evaluating on it.
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMapGrid1f(100, 0.0, 1.0);
    glEvalMesh1(GL_LINE, 0, 100);
    // Draw the Bezier control points as dots.
    glPointSize(5.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (indx = 0; indx < 4; indx++)
        glVertex3fv(controlPoints[indx]);
    glEnd();

    // Highlight selected control point,
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3fv(controlPoints[numVal]);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50.0, 50.0, -50.0, 50.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case ' ':
        if (numVal < 3) numVal++;
            else numVal = 0;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

// Callback routine for non-ASCII key entry.
void specialKeyInput(int key, int x, int y)
{

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP) controlPoints[numVal][2] += 1.0;
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) controlPoints[numVal][2] -= 1.0;
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) controlPoints[numVal][0] -= 1.0;
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) controlPoints[numVal][0] += 1.0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Routine to output interaction instructions to the console window.
void printInteraction(void)
{
    printf("Interaction:\n");
    printf("Press space to select a control point.\n");
    printf("Press the arrow keys to move the selected control point.\n");
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Interpolating Curves");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyInput);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    setup();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Your "conversion[][]" matrix is not fully utilized as the for loop will go from k=0 to k=2 only. This may be the cause.

Comment: That was very stupid of me but it's actually the correct answer lol. Thanks fang

Comment: Worth noting that OpenGL evaluators are really old and deprecated, and you are likely off using a different library to do stuff like that.